# BS4 with Python 3.6 Web Scraping, how to find text behind the exactly 4th instance of a certain <font> string?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup4 on Python3.6 to web scrape a generated page. The information is always laid out exactly the same, but the information itself changes, which is what I'm scraping.

Imports: BeautifulSoup4, LXML, Tkinter, Sys, OS, Time

I've been using a basic soup.find to get the first bit of information, which is easy since it's always the very first tag.

```
<font face="Arial" size="-1">
```

Scraping that with:

```
information = soup.find('font', {'face': 'Arial', 'size': '-1'}).b.div.previousSibling
```

always pulls what I'm looking for, which is [important information]. This is all in the `<body>`, with the first bit scraping successfully.

The issue I'm having is, I need the information that's just after the 4th instance of the tag

```
<font face="Arial" size="-1" color="BLACK">informationIneed</font>
```

Which is inside the same line as several instances of

```
<td align="right"><font face="Arial" size="-1" color="BLACK">INFORMATION I NEED</font></td>
```

But the information changes.

When I replace the soup.find that pulls the first bit of information and turn it into

```
information = soup.find('font', {'face': 'Arial', 'size': '-1', 'color': 'BLACK'}).b.div.previousSibling
```

I get "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'previousSibling'. I assume this is because the information I'm browsing for doesn't have `<div>` or `<b>` tags, but the code I'm using wasn't generated myself and I'm still unfamiliar with how to adjust it correctly. Replacing `.b.div.previousSibling` with `.td.previousSibling` doesn't work and I'm not sure what else I should try.

TL;DR, does anyone know how to get the information directly after the 4th instance of `<font face="Arial" size="-1" color="BLACK">` OR directly after the SECOND instance of `<td align="right"><font face="Arial" size="-1" color="BLACK">`?

Edit 1: An easier way is to find the next integer, which can go up to the triple digits.

It looks like `<td align="right"><font face="Arial" size="-1" color="BLACK">&nbsp;1</font>`, where I'd want to scrape the 1 just before `</font>`.  `<td align="right"><font face="Arial" size="-1" color="BLACK">` is not unique, there are two. The one I am hunting for is the second occurrence of this string.

**Edit 2:** SOLUTION!

```
with open("output.html") as url:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'lxml')
    tags = soup.findAll('font', {'face': 'Arial', 'size': '-1', 'color': 'BLACK'})
    print('There are {} matching tags'.format(len(tags)))
    print('Second: {}'.format(tags[3]))
```

I will leave this on the internet for any other folks having similar issues and can't grasp the documentation. Just be aware that it counts from 0, not 1. tags[0] is the first instance. Just keep printing more numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are looking for `findAll` which returs a list of all occurences of a tag instead of just returning the first occurence.

```
info = soup.findAll('font', {'face': 'Arial', 'size': '-1'})[4].text
```

should give what you need...

Comment: Found the solution independently but this is very similar to what I already have. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Use `bs.find_all` and set a limit to first `N` matches found.

```
result = soup.find_all(
    'font', {'face': 'Arial', 'size': -1, 'color': 'BLACK'}, limit=4
)
information = result[-1].text
print(information)
```

Answer (score 0):

Collect the list of tags you're interested in:

```
list_of_tags = soup.find_all('font', {'face': 'Arial', 'size': '-1', 'color': 'BLACK'})
```

Using [islice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to get the desired elemtents:

```
from itertools import islice

infos = islice(list_of_tags, 4, 5)   
# will be an empty list if less than 5 elements in it
if infos:
    print(infos[0].text)
```

Does this give you what you wanted?